# JS Facebook login iOS8

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The login button on my facebook app has completely stopped working in iOS 8. I thought it was something I have done but when I take facebooks sample html from their site and apply it to my page it still doesnt work (my app id has been replaced with xxxxx). Basically the pop up window opens for facebook auth but never closes and returns to my app. Im just left with a blank which tab open:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
            // app know the current login status of the person.
            // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
            // for FB.getLoginStatus().
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                testAPI();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                  'into this app.';
            } else {
                // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                // they are logged into this app or not.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                  'into Facebook.';
            }
        }

        // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
        // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
        // code below.
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
                xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version: 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
            });

            // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
            // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
            // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
            // the callback you provide.  They can be:
            //
            // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
            // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
            // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
            //    your app or not.
            //
            // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });

        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
        // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                  'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            });
        }
    </script>
    <!--
      Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
      the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
      the FB.login() function when clicked.
    -->

    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    </fb:login-button>

    <div id="status">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Further info: the page wont redirect back from this url https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/arbiter?

Comment: Looks like a facebook bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295178237341368/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I came up with is to degrade back to the server-side authentication flow when on iOS using full on redirects.  Basically your app should hit a URL like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

Which is a jarring experience on desktop, but is arguably a nicer experience on mobile, given that the user isn’t taken through the weird tab switching (which is the root of the new problem in the first place).  To degrade to this flow ONLY on iOS, make sure your sign-in link is actually an href to the facebook authentication dialog (like the link above, or for you omniauth users on rails, is “/auth/facebook”).  Then wrap the javascript where you invoke the client side flow in code that prevents it from being run on iOS (or all of mobile, if you want).

```
if(!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
[Facebook client side flow code here]
}
```

(please let me know in comments if anyone has a more elegant way of doing this)

Comment: nice work marc! Cant believe the number of things i have found broken in iOS8 this week. You would think its still beta!