# Facebook login popup doesn't close after login on iOS8

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm testing my web app login flow on the iOS8. I notice that on iOS8, the login dialogue pops up, but after logging in, it just stays there, showing a blank page.

The login works, because the page behind it shows the user information, but the popup just stays there, while it should close automatically. On iOS7 and iOS6 it does close. On desktop browsers it closes too.

I've tested some other random sites (for example [brainfall.com](http://www.brainfall.com)) using `FB.login()`: same thing.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: happened to me as well, seems like just another ios8 bug. You might wanna gt back to server side authentication as said here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26052127/2880184

Comment: Thanks, works great, and doesn't look as awful as it does on dekstop.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:
[fb_window_redirect](https://github.com/solorulo/fb_window_redirect)

Override de window.open method. This allows you to know what windows are opened.

Then you can redirect the window opened by the FB SDK.

```
...
window._open = window.open; // saving original function
//Override the function
window.open = function(url,name,params) {
    var new_window = window._open(url,name,params);
    if (typeof onWindowOpen === "function") {
        onWindowOpen(url, name, params, new_window);
    }
    return new_window;
};
...
var openedWindows = [];
var fbWindows = [];
function onWindowOpen(url, name, params, new_window) {
    ...
    // Filter the facebook oauth request
    if (url.contains('facebook.com') 
    && url.contains('oauth')) {
        fbWindows.push(new_window);
    }
    openedWindows.push(new_window);
}
...
//On fb login button pressed callback:
FB.login(function(response) {
    //Try login
    if(response.authResponse) {
        //Login succesful
        // Fb window redirect.
        // see onWindowOpen
        var fbwin = fbWindows[0];
        var redirect_url = ''
        fbwin.location = redirect_url;
    }
},
{scope: 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday'});
...
```